# Looking at CPU load

Tags: arm, load, cpu, bare

I'd like to have some advices because I'm stuck !

I need to measure the CPU load on my device (Hercules RM48 for instance). However, it's programmed in bare metal so I don't have access to the classic Linux commands.

How would you do to have an idea of this consumption and be sure, for example, that you are not using more than 50% of CPU load ?

Thanks for helping me !